# Finding and Editing HTML Elements in PHP

Tags: php, html

First off sorry for being a complete newb and if this is a something I shouldn't be bothering people with, but I am fairly new to PHP and I have been tasked by my employer to make a couple of changes to a website that seems to be written primarily in PHP.

The website is ems-uk.co.uk

I have been asked just to check the location on the maps that display on the pages but I can't for the life of me find the file to edit within the file manager. I can find exactly what I need to change when I "inspect element" in Chrome but cannot find anything even close in the index.php file and there appears to be no other files for separate pages.

Hope someone can direct me in the right area and sorry again if this is the wrong arena for a question like this.

Comment: Try a google search for 'Simple HTML DOM Parser', a very usefull PHP library to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of inspection suggest this is an OpenCart powered CMS/ecom site with the Kuler Moment theme (skin 3). I'm not familiar with the OpenCart dashboard but you may be able to log in and configure the google maps module from there. Failing that I would look in the theme files for the location map section.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to it wrong. PHP is server sided, you're trying to edit things client side.

You will need access to the webserver and edit code there. If you're asking this I'm not sure if its good if you're editing pages on that website though.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference between server side and client side but I think you're probably right and I'll advise that this is outside my current skill set.